# How to get information about spawned children from their PID

Tags: c++, process, fork, execv

In my program I am spawning child processes by using fork and execv. I am saving the child PIDs in an array. How can I get information about the children by using these PIDs? I want to get information like how much memory and CPU they are using.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the library [libgtop](http://developer.gnome.org/libgtop/stable/)
or instead directly parse the contents of

> /proc/PID/stat

Comment: I'm not on OS X bout you could try to run system_profiler from command line and parse the output. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702870/how-to-collect-system-info-in-osx-using-objective-c