# How do I detect apple silicon (M1) vs. intel in swift 5.0?

Tags: swift

I make a call to ffmpeg and ffprobe.  This issue I have is that Brew installs them in different locations based on architecture.  On an Intel machine the binaries are installed in /usr/local/bin, but on the M1 the binaries are installed in /opt/homebrew/bin.

I'd like to do something like:

```
let ffprobe = Process()
if intel {
    ffprobe.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/local/bin/ffprobe")
} else {
    ffprobe.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/opt/homebrew/bin/ffprobe")
}
```

I have searched for this and cannot find anything.

Comment: What about checking if file exist at path before hand with `FilleManager`?

Comment: Yeah, that’s what I’ve done now. However, I’m still curious about the way one checks for the type of architecture in Swift.

Comment: I guess that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702870/how-to-collect-system-info-in-osx-using-objective-c might have some infos, but that would need some work.

Comment: At least it's a start!  Thank you @Larme!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got this answer from the Apple Developer Forums:

```
var systeminfo = utsname()
uname(&systeminfo)
let machine = withUnsafeBytes(of: &systeminfo.machine) {bufPtr->String in
    let data = Data(bufPtr)
    if let lastIndex = data.lastIndex(where: {$0 != 0}) {
        return String(data: data[0...lastIndex], encoding: .isoLatin1)!
    } else {
        return String(data: data, encoding: .isoLatin1)!
    }
}
print(machine)
```

Here's the link for reference [Apple Developer Forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/678914).

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if things have changed in a year, but I found Apple forums suggested a much simpler approach using `ProcessInfo` -- ie;

let proc_info = ProcessInfo()
proc_info.isiOSAppOnMac

There are also Catalyst bools. Worked great to detect my iOS app running on MacOS Silicon (non Catalyst).

see
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/processinfo/3608556-isiosapponmac